# software updates/deployment across a network of servers

Tags: linux, deployment, packages

Interested in getting opinions for a possible project.

Got a master server, where apps are created/maintained. The system will have a process where the client network will consist of 400-500 client servers (all running linux X).

The process needs a system to have the clients pull the new/modified updates/software, from the master service.

The software to be placed on the clients will consist of scripts (perl/py/php) as well as java apps, which will also require the supporting class/libs.

Looking for thoughts/opinions on how this kind of process can be implemented.

I've reviewed apps like spacewalk, as well as other package managers.

Anything else I should be looking into??

Thanks

Comment: Search ServerFault for posts about puppet, chef, radmind, etc. -- do any of these meet your needs?

Answer (score 1):

Package your updates in your distributions native package management format, and then use the tools that come with the distribution, in combination with the usual release management practices, to have your updates roll out where they need to roll out, and when.